# Redefine border of image no longer selected

Tags: jquery, html, border

I am creating a form where some elements are images. When hovered over, there is a CSS rule that creates a thick border around the selected image. This is also true for when an image is selected; it leaves a thick border.

The problem I am faced with though is that when an image is clicked, whilst it leaves a thick border around the correct image, it doesn't redefine the borders around other previous selected images. (By redefine I mean make it translucent to stop the image from moving about).

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bewWF/ or you may see the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid_12 alpha" id="selection">

    <input type="hidden" id="SelSunlight" name="SelSunlight" value=""/>

    <div class="grid_2 omega" style="margin-left: 8px">
        <div align="center"><img src="images/details/any.png"/ id="AnySun" name="AnySun" onClick="SelectSunlight('AnySun')"/></div>
        <p id="image-text">Any</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_2 alpha omega">
        <div align="center"><img src="images/details/sunlight/full_light.png" id="FullSun" name="FullSun" onClick="SelectSunlight('FullSun')"/></div>
        <p id="image-text">Full Sun</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_2 alpha omega">
        <div align="center"><img src="images/details/sunlight/part_shade.png" id="PartShade" name="PartShade" onClick="SelectSunlight('PartShade')"/></div>
        <p id="image-text">Part Shade</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_2 alpha">
        <div align="center"><img src="images/details/sunlight/full_shade.png" id="FullShade" name="FullShade" onClick="SelectSunlight('FullShade')"/></div>
        <p id="image-text">Full Shade</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function SelectSunlight(item) {
    $.each(['#AnySun','#FullSun','#PartShade','#FullShade'], function() {
        $(this).css('border', "3px solid #f5f5f5");

        $(this).hover( function() {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        });
    });

    $('#'+item).css('border', "3px solid #a6be39");
    $('#SelSunlight').val(item);
}
```

`.hover` is defined as `#selection .hover {border: 3px solid #a6be39}`

I've resolved problem after problem and after spending a lengthy amount of time I've finally ran out of ideas with regards to this problem. My head suggests it should work, but evidently it doesn't!

What needs to be done:

1) User selects an image
2) Once an image is selected, the border for that image remains thick
3) All other images must keep the hover effect, whereby the border becomes thick and thin respectively
4) If another image is then selected, the border in step 2 is reset, and the new image takes on a thick border

This image may make it clearer: http://i48.tinypic.com/ei4f9t.png

Comment: I updated my post. Let me know if I'm missing any of your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could simplify that a lot:

```
$(function() {
    $('#AnySun, #FullSun, #PartShade, #FullShade').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover').siblings('img').removeClass('hover');
        $('#SelSunlight').val(this.id);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4NP9J/)

Comment: This doesn't change the value of `#SelSunlight`

Comment: @Mooseman - That's just so trivial I did'nt even think to add it, but thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @adeneo Not sure if I'm just being stupid, but http://gyazo.com/575be004cb0234c8cd671f336feb2873 doesn't work. I'm using the following jQuery v: http://gyazo.com/91f0f2c91fc5ab25d710290f9d918a60 - any ideas?

Comment: @JYoung - You probably need to wrap the code in a DOM ready function. Added that as well.

Comment: @adeneo I tried that last night after my latest comment but it causes the border to stick when another image is selected. Live example here: http://www.jonline.me.uk/fbedder/details.php - ignore the errors, I removed the session check so that you need not login. I've tried positioning the function in the head, before the images are defined, and after the images are defined but none have worked.

Comment: @JYoung - That's because you're using some sort of grid layout, so the images are no longer siblings, like they are in your question. You probably need a class to target all the images, otherwise it will be hard to do when they are all over the place in the DOM.

Comment: @adeneo I've tried giving a parent class around the images, I've tried stating a class in each grid, and I've even tried setting the class name on each img element but nothing has worked. I set siblings to the class name as well. Am I missing what you are suggesting??

Answer (score 1):

I optimized all your code. Since you're using CSS `:hover`, you don't need to use jQuery for the hover border. I added `class="sun"` to each of the images so that you wouldn't need to use `$(".sun")` instead of the slower `.each`. I use jQuery's `.click` to replace `onclick` and `.prop` to get the name attribute the clicked `.sun`. I changed the selected img border red for the demo.

HTML:

```
<div id="selection">
    <input type="hidden" id="SelSunlight" name="SelSunlight" value="" />
    <img class="sun" src="http://jonline.me.uk/fbedder/images/details/any.png" id="AnySun" name="AnySun" />
        <p id="image-text">Any</p>
    <img class="sun" src="http://jonline.me.uk/fbedder/images/details/sunlight/full_light.png" id="FullSun" name="FullSun" />
        <p id="image-text">Full Sun</p>
    <img class="sun" src="http://jonline.me.uk/fbedder/images/details/sunlight/part_shade.png" id="PartShade" name="PartShade" />
        <p id="image-text">Part Shade</p>
    <img class="sun" src="http://jonline.me.uk/fbedder/images/details/sunlight/full_shade.png" id="FullShade" name="FullShade" />
        <p id="image-text">Full Shade</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sun {border: 3px solid #f5f5f5}
.sun:hover {border: 3px solid #a6be39}
.selected {border: 3px solid red !important}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sun").click(function(){
        $(".sun").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        var item = $(this).prop("name");
        $('#SelSunlight').val(item);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bewWF/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all the borders before selecting the current one. Is that what you are looking for?

```
function SelectSunlight(item) {
    $("img").css('border','3px solid #f5f5f5'); //resets border of all images
    $.each(['#AnySun', '#FullSun', '#PartShade', '#FullShade'], function () {
        $(this).css('border', "3px solid #f5f5f5"); 

        $(this).hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        });
    });

    $('#' + item).css('border', "3px solid #a6be39");
    $('#SelSunlight').val(item);
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/bewWF/1/

Comment: Not quite what I was after, I updated my main post to make it more clear! Thanks for your time though.